I have Lenovo legion y540 and Ubuntu 20.04 on it , i have some probems because my wifi icon is disappear and i can't also run internet with ethernet
I was trying to download my gpu drivers because it isn't found after i finish with the same steps my friend try and done it need to reboot and when it open i can't find the wifi icon and also touch bad isn't working and Bluetooth not working also and when i try to connect an ethernet cable nothing is appear also can't connect internet from my phone using usb

I find it helpful when doing the initial install of Ubuntu to choose to connect to WiFi so after reboot your machine has a working WiFi from the start ...  in the past I have installed Ubuntu onto several Lenovo laptops so if your hardware is working then Ubuntu can work fine too ...  when asking a question on this forum I suggest you focus onto a single question not many

If i was you, I would reinstall Ubuntu. I had this on Windows, and after reinstalling Windows, Wi-Fi, Ethernet and Bluetooth worked, maybe the same will happen after reinstalling Ubuntu.

Look at the network logs with the terminal command: sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager. Read man journalctl NetworkManager service. Also do: service NetworkManager status and service --status-all.
